# Nativescript angular 2 error while import multiple components

Tags: angular, nativescript

When i import 2 components `within directives:[]` the second component comes with this error `File stores.component.xml does not exists`.

**What Works**

When there is only 1 component in `directives: []` or use template instead of templateUrl

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { ChatsComponent } from './chats/chats.component';
import { StoresComponent } from './stores/stores.component';

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: 'app.component.xml',
    directives:[ ChatsComponent, StoresComponent ]
})
```

app.component.xml

```
<TabView>
  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Chats'}">
    <chats></chats>
  </StackLayout>

  <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Store'}">
    <stores></stores>
  </StackLayout>
</TabView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nativescript removes angular `module.id` so `templateUrl` requires absolute path which `templateUrl: 'app.component.xml',` to `templateUrl: '../app/YOUR_COMPONENT_DIRECTORY/NAME.component.xml'`

Comment: That would work. It's relative to the app folder so you could skip the *app* part so it becomes more simply:
`YOUR_COMPONENT_DIRECTORY/NAME.component.html` or `./YOUR_COMPONENT_DIRECTORY/NAME.component.html`. The preference for the file extension is html as @Houssem mentions as the tooling tends to work better and the ide tends to complain less about your view.

Answer (score 1):

In nativescript 2, using ng2, the `'templateUrl'` file's extension is in fact a `'.html'` and not a `'.xml'`